# Java using substring() to reverse String

Tags: java

How is the String passed to this method getting reversed? If you pass "ABCD" the string become "DCBA", but I was thinking reverse(str.substring(1)) will call it self until it return "D" which will be concatenated with str.substring(0,1) which is D and the string returned to be "DD".JAVA programming Language.

```
private static String reverse(String str) {
    if (str.length() <= 1) {
        return str;
    }
    return reverse(str.substring(1)) + str.substring(0, 1);
}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Do you know how recursion works? *reverse(str.substring(1)) will call it self until it return "D" which will be concatinated with str.substring(0,1) wich is D and the string returned to be "DD"* - No.  Did you try debugging?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your best bet with things like this is to work it through on paper and/or step through it statement by statement in the debugger built into your IDE.

- `reverse("ABCD")` returns `reverse("BCD") + "A"`. This is recursion. The call hasn't returned yet, because it needs the result of `reverse("BCD")` before it can add `"A"` to it and return.

  - `reverse("BCD")` returns `reverse("CD") + "B"`, which waits for `reverse("CD")` to return

    - `reverse("CD")` returns `reverse("D") + "C"`, which waits for `reverse("D")` to return

      - `reverse("D")` returns `"D"`
    - The result of `reverse("D") + "C"` is `"DC"`, so now `reverse("CD")` can return `"DC"`
  - The result of `reverse("CD") + "B"` is `"DCB"`, so now `reverse("BCD")` can return `"DCB"`
- The result of `reverse("BCD") + "A"` is `"DCBA"`, so now `reverse("ABCD")` can return `"DCBA"`

Comment: Thanks for the Quick response.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the following procedure to solve your problem:

```
String reversed = new StringBuilder(str).reverse().toString();
```

Also, according to the requirements about thread safety you can use StringBuffer or StringBuilder